# Custom message where key is not present in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

By definition ruby hashes return nil when a key is not present. But I need to use a custom message in the place of nil. So I'm using something like this:

```
val = h['key'].nil? ? "No element present" : h['key']
```

But this has a serious drawback. If there's a assigned nil against the key this will return "No element present" in that case also.

Is there a way to achieve this flawlessly?

Thanks

Comment: The question is “How to know if a key is present in the hash”, not “How to return something else than _nil_” ;-)

Comment: The important question is whether you want all accesses of this hash to behave this way, or whether you just need a custom message in *this* case (assigning to `val` at this point in your program). The latter is much safer, and Tarscher and Sarwar both have your answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Initialize your hash this way:

```
> hash = Hash.new{|hash,key| hash[key] = "No element against #{key}"}
 => {}
> hash['a']
 => "No element against a" 
> hash['a'] = 123
 => 123 
> hash['a'] 
 => 123 
> hash['b'] = nil
 => nil 
> hash['b']
 => nil
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: The question is “How to know if a key is present in the hash”, not “How to return something else than _nil_” ;-)

Comment: This will actually store "No element against #{key}" as a value. DNNX answer is better.

Comment: @steenslag: Oh yes, I never thought this way. Very true. I agree DNNX's answer is more suitable. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 3):

```
irb(main):001:0> h = Hash.new('No element present')
=> {}
irb(main):002:0> h[1]
=> "No element present"
irb(main):003:0> h[1] = nil
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> h[1]
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> h[2]
=> "No element present"
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `has_key?` method instead

```
val = h.has_key?('key') ? h['key'] : "No element present"
```

Comment: I always found `key?` clearer (and shorter, obviously) than `has_key?`. Aliases for the same method...

Answer (score 0):

```
val = h.has_key?("key") ? h['key'] : "No element present"
```